# Similar Triangles with proportions

Tags: geometry, triangles

In $\triangle ABC$, $AB=8, BC=7, CA=6$, and side $BC$ is extended to point $P$, so that $\triangle PAB$ is similar to $\triangle PCA$. Find the length of $PC$.

Comment: i originally got 21 by doing (8/6)=pa/pc=pb/pa, but i dont think thats correct. i have the proportions, i just dont know how to continue

Answer (score 0):

Corresponding sides tell you $\frac {AB}{AC}=\frac {PB}{PA}=\frac 43=\frac {7+PC}{PA}=\frac{PA}{PC}$

Comment: PC is part of triangle PCA

Comment: the common angle is P (triangle PAB and PCA)

Comment: @Ari:  I misread.  Fixing

Comment: thank you! i tried solving for PA then solving for PC and got 9.

Comment: That looks good.  Both triangles are similar to $2,3,4$